# problem in nested query Mysql question

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1242

below is my query and I am getting a "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error:

```
INSERT INTO billing_temp (`billing_period_id`,`soc_id`,`bill_y_n`) 
  VALUES(
      (SELECT `id` FROM `billing_period` ORDER BY `billing_start_date` DESC LIMIT 0,1),
      (SELECT `id` FROM `milk_producer` WHERE active='1'),
      'N'
  )

SELECT `id` FROM `billing_period` ORDER BY `billing_start_date` DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

returns multiple values.

I want that these multiple values will insert into table, e.g:

```
1 03 N
2 03 N
3 03 N
```

Comment: thats not possible with that syntax. you have to loop throud all results from `SELECT id FROM billing_period order by billing_start_date DESC LIMIT 0,1`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you [can't](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) perform an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` *and* and `INSERT INTO ... VALUES`. Choose one.

In your case, there is an illogical correlation upon inserting data by row -- unless `milk_producer` only has 1 row `WHERE active='1'`. Similarly, if you're trying to load multiple rows, why are you `LIMIT`ing the inner query to 1 result?

```
INSERT INTO billing_temp (`billing_period_id`,`soc_id`,`bill_y_n`)
    SELECT `id`, ??, 'N' FROM `billing_period` 
    ORDER BY `billing_start_date` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the `SELECT` statement. Have a look at cursors.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html